# custom tabbar in xcode

Tags: iphone, xcode4.2

i am new in xcode development. I want to create a custom tab bar not using the tabbar application or using the storyboard , i want to make it programmatically . Can it be possible. I have go-through with this  [Video Tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JDPkyltAqmo) but when i am trying to release the tab, there giving error. Can anyone help me.Here is my code,

```
main_tab = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
    viewController1 = [[Firstview alloc] init];
    viewController1.title = @"View 1";
    UINavigationController *nav1 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController1];

    viewController2 = [[SecondView alloc] init];
    viewController2.title = @"View 2";
    UINavigationController *nav2 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController2];
```

And i am using xcode 4.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using ARC, you do not need to retain or release objects anymore.

Comment: but nothing is appearing when i try to run. Do u have any example of custom navigation bar.

Answer (score 0):

You can enable or disable ARC by clicking on the project file and selecting the corresponding property. [Here](http://matthiaswessendorf.wordpress.com/2011/09/12/disabling-the-arc-in-xcode-4-2/) you have a good description.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using storyboard then there should be starting point.
so take a uitabarcontroller in storyboard as starting point and link a reference to  tabBarController

```
 NSMutableArray *listOfViewControllers = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
UIViewController *vc;

vc = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
vc.title = @"A";
[listOfViewControllers addObject:vc];
[vc release];
vc = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
vc.title = @"B";
[listOfViewControllers addObject:vc];
[vc release];
vc = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
vc.title = @"C";
[listOfViewControllers addObject:vc];
[vc release];

[self.tabBarController setViewControllers:listOfViewControllers
                                 animated:YES];
```

}

Without storyboard and without taking UITabbarController in XIB

```
UITabBarController *tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
```

NSMutableArray *listOfViewControllers = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    UIViewController *vc;

```
vc = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
vc.title = @"A";
[listOfViewControllers addObject:vc];
[vc release];
vc = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
vc.title = @"B";
[listOfViewControllers addObject:vc];
[vc release];
vc = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
vc.title = @"C";
[listOfViewControllers addObject:vc];
[vc release];

[tabBarController setViewControllers:listOfViewControllers
                                 animated:YES];
```

Comment: If you used ARC then just remove [vc release];